# Preview of static asset in admin panel

Tags: java, broadleaf-commerce

How do I preview some static asset in the admin panel ? Is there any way to download it ? Field config in entity class is following:

```
   @Column(name = "ASSET_FILE")
   @AdminPresentation(friendlyName = "Asset_file", fieldType = SupportedFieldType.ASSET_LOOKUP,
           group = SomeClass.GroupName.IMAGE)
   private String assetFile;
```

User has the possibility to upload his profile file (not necessarily image), and as an admin I would like to be able to preview and download it (from the customer profile in admin panel).

fieldType = SupportedFieldType.ASSET_LOOKUP gives only the chance to upload file from the list or remove the current one.

View from the admin panel after uploading .pdf file:
[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good enhancement to make this automatic, perhaps open an issue at https://githbu.com/BroadleafCommerce/Issues?

As a workaround, when you view the file in the admin, it has a URL field. To actually load that URL, you can prefix the url with `/cmssstatic` for Broadleaf to resolve it.

For example, if you updload a file `file.pdf` then you should see in the admin that the URL is `/file.pdf`. To actually get to that file, go to `https://localhost:8444/admin/cmsstatic/file.pdf` in your browser.

You can also access this on the frontend with `https://localhost:8443/cmsstatic/file.pdf`.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a good workaround. The only thing I'll have to add is removing signs from the uploaded file's name that makes URL invalid. Thanks ;)